# How to access propery file in java Spring non-controller class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My non-controller class will be ,

```
public class Authorization {
String licensePath ;

@Value("${licenseKeyNotFound}")
String licenseKeyNotFound;

    public boolean checkIn(String licensepath) {
    System.out.println("hello "+licenseKeyNotFound);
    licensePath = licensepath;
    return checkIn();
    }

}
```

Here is my properties file.

```
licenseKeyNotFound = License File Corrupted
```

my `login-servlet.xml` will be ,

```
<context:property-placeholder location="conf/LicenseSettings.properties"
     order="2" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

I didn,t put it in the applicationcontext.xml.Is that right ?

Comment: Is `Authorization` a Spring Bean?  It should either be annotated(`@Component`, `@Service`, etc.) and scanned or configured through xml or a `@Configuration`.  Since you're using `@Value` you probably want the annotation option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Authorization is not a Spring Bean.I dont know how to read the properties file in the Authorization class.Please guide me to solve this ...

Comment: Here's the quick scanned annotation route: Annotate the Authorization class with `@Component` or `@Service` depending on which makes more sense in your app (they'll work the same way).  Add `<context:component-scan ...` to your config file with an appropriate `base-package` attribute to pick up the package that `Authorization` is in.   Spring only injects if it is managing the bean.

Answer (score 1):

I think Spring hasn't found the location `location="conf/LicenseSettings.properties"` and because you have set `ignore-unresolvable="true"` it isn't complaining about it.

Try putting the files in classpath and use `classpath:LicenseSettings.properties` or use an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...But not helped...Any more sugesstions.

Comment: @Anand You should remove `ignore-unresolvable` either way in this case.  You have a literal file name that you are expecting to be there, if it isn't there it is an error that should be recognized.  `ignore-unresolvable` is useful if you have multiple files (likely with dynamic environment driven names) but some are optional (and therefore their absence is not an error).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem that you put this in the `servlet.xml` but should in the spring config a `applicationContext.xml`

```
<context:property-placeholder location="conf/LicenseSettings.properties"
     order="2" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

Comment: I don't see how it matters especially when one can rename the `applicationContext.xml` to anything they like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I put this in login-servlet.xml . Where I need to put this ? login-servlet.xml or applicationContext.xml ?

Comment: @adarshr I don't know really OP didn't say that

Comment: @Anand Put it in the *Spring* config what name matters

Comment: This answer is misinformed.

_Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml_
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: See also [4.14.4](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-introduction) in that reference

Comment: In a stratified configuration something like applicationContext.xml should be used for the root context and then the `-servlet.xml` could be used for the MVC specific context(s) if warranted. None of this changes the fact that your answer is misleading in that the `-servlet.xml` file is a Spring configuration file while you implied it wasn't.  The answer would only have a chance of being relevant if there are multiple application contexts but that is unlikely and also not mentioned at all in your answer.

Comment: @MattWhipple I've meant that "servlet xml" as been initially in the OP's post not a spring config, even now OP has not mention this. I my answer I've made a statement that I mean the spring config.